# filter out the dataframe after groupby operations

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to groupby the following dataframe and after filter after grouping by.

how to check if the corresponding value of col2 is True for groups of col1

The input dataframe looks like

```
col1    col2    col3
1   True    p1
1   True    p2
1   True    p3
1   True    p4
2   False   p1
2   True    p2
2   True    p3
2   True    p4
3   False   p1
3   False   p2
3   False   p3
3   False   p4
4   True    p1
4   True    p2
4   True    p3
4   True    p4
```

I tried groupby and filter

```
filtered_df = df.groupby(['col1']).filter(lambda final_filter : final_filter['col2'] is True)
```

the final output looks like this

output:

```
col1    col2    col3
1   True    p1
1   True    p2
1   True    p3
1   True    p4
4   True    p1
4   True    p2
4   True    p3
4   True    p4
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('all')]`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `all` on 'col2' in the `filter`:

```
print (df.groupby('col1').filter(lambda x: x.col2.all()))
    col1  col2 col3
0      1  True   p1
1      1  True   p2
2      1  True   p3
3      1  True   p4
12     4  True   p1
13     4  True   p2
14     4  True   p3
15     4  True   p4
```